Redirecting .html links to 410 didn't work
I want to redirect all links ending in ".html" to 410. I added the following line to .htaccess but it didn't work:
RewriteRule ^.*\.html$ - [R=410,L]

I also added the following code in 404.php for permanently redirecting missing pages to the homepage.
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: ".get_bloginfo('url'));
exit();

When I remove redirect for 404 pages, and check .html link in redirect checker, returns 410 for the first time. But after that, returns 404!
What is the best way to achieve this?
